# Burninate [json-schema-validator]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Json-schema is a standard (still draft) for json data structure validation. A [jsonschema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonschema) tag exist.

A high percentage of jsonschema questions (273 up today) involve some kind of validator, but only 8 use [json-schema-validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-schema-validator) tag.

Nevertheless concrete validator implementations are tagged with more frequency ([json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json.net) x 28, [jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jackson) x  15).

So most of questions related with validators are not tagged with this tag, or they use the concrete validator implementation tag or the programming language tag, which seems more descriptive.

So I suggest burninate [json-schema-validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-schema-validator).

Comment: Apparently that tag was created for yet another concrete implementation [json-schema-validator](http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/).  I don't know how many of the questions are using it in that fashion, but that would seem to indicate some validity to the tag.

Comment: You are right. But just 6 of 14 questions refer to that concrete validator. This is due to the unfortunate name of the library (which is too generic). So no nice solution to this. ¿Perhaps change the tag to fge-json-schema-validator?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.

Comment: And how could that be done?